# How can I change value of angular object used in HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to change a value in HTML using Angular click. The value is getting changed in the angular function but it is not reflecting in HTML.
My Angularjs and HTML is like :-

```js
$scope.GetTblData = function (Name) {
        var Data = $.param({ TblName: Name });
        var MyTblDataList = [];

        $scope.TempName = '';
        $scope.TempName = Name;

        if (Name == 'ContactTbl') {
            $('#ContactTbl').show();
            $('#CourseTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
            $('#InternTbl').hide();
            $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        }
        else if (Name == 'CourseTbl') {
            $('#ContactTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseTbl').show();
            $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
            $('#InternTbl').hide();
            $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        }
        else if (Name == 'CourseDescTbl') {
            $('#ContactTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseDescTbl').show();
            $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
            $('#InternTbl').hide();
            $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        }
        else if (Name == 'CourseSubDesc') {
            $('#ContactTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseSubDescTbl').show();
            $('#InternTbl').hide();
            $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        }
        else if (Name == 'InternTbl') {
            $('#ContactTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
            $('#InternTbl').show();
            $('#LocationTbl').hide();
        }
        else if (Name == 'LocationTbl') {
            $('#ContactTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseDescTbl').hide();
            $('#CourseSubDescTbl').hide();
            $('#InternTbl').hide();
            $('#LocationTbl').show();
        }

        $http({
            url: '/Admin/FetchTblData',
            method: 'POST',
            data: Data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.MyTblDataList = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            alert('Cannot Load Table data')
        });
    }//GetTblData End
```

```html
<li ng-repeat="r in MyTblList">
                            <a href="#" data-ng-click="GetTblData(r.TblName)">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                {{r.TblName}}
                            </a>
                        </li>

<h2>{{TempName}} Details</h2>


<div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="CourseTbl" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="margin:0px 5px; width:1070px">
            <thead style="background-color:aqua">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        S. No.
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Image
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        CourseLink
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Action
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="r in MyTblDataList">
                    <td>
                        {{$index+1}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{r.ID}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{r.Name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{r.Description}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="~/img/course-img/{{r.Img}}" height="200px" width="200px" />
                        @*{{r.Img}}*@
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{r.CourseLink}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn btn-group-xs">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" ng-click="editItem(r.ID)" value="Edit" />
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="Delete" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

But the problem is that on click of the anchor tag the value of $scope.TempName changes in Angularjs function but value of {{TempName}} doesn't change.

Comment: what is the `r` object? it's unclear!

Comment: r is for each item in list. See modified question.

Comment: I'm sorry didn't get you.

Comment: I double checked, but I don't see any references to {{TempName}}

Comment: the problem is for $scope.TempName . How will change in $scope.MyTblDataList effect it?

Comment: @roland $scope.TempName in angularjs will be used as {{TempName}} in HTML.

Comment: `GetTblData` function not modify `MyTblList` array.

Comment: @Hadi My Mistake . I've only showed some part of function I'm retrieving the list later on inside the function.

Comment: @Deepak: the code is uncleared, however, I think you are trying to populate data on click event in that case on click handler function you need to push data into "MyTblList" which is the variable you are iterating over

Comment: @Sohail I've modified the code and copied the complete code. Hope I have made it clear now. {{TempName}} I'm using as an html control and MyTblList I'm populating seperately.

Comment: @Deepak : check this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/sohail85/pg9Lwtp3/
I could not found any issue with the way you are doing, it might be some error in your code which causes angular to stop interpolating your variable. regarding the way you are displaying tables I would rather reuse the same table for all your data rather than hiding and showing your template based on the selected table (may be you have some reason for that which I am not aware of), if still you have any issue it would be good to share sample fiddle